# error getting the names of columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, names

i am currently working on a friend's code, the problem is that although in his R session it works successfully, in mines I have problems at the time I try to do this:

```
a_discretizar <- names(df[a_discretizar])
```

It should work fine since df is a data frame, and the variable (a_discretizar) is a character variable, so the aim is to get the column names of the data frame and storing in the same variable.

Comment: What is the point of doing this? The object `a_discretizar` isn't going to change, is it?

Comment: yeah because at first in the variable I have ( TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,TRUE,FALSE.... etc) and the after doing this I would want the column names of the variable df corresponding the TRUE values

Comment: Ohh so `a_discretizar` is not a character variable, but a logical one. Anyway, the code should indeed work. Could you share a sample data using `dput(head(df))` and the original `a_discretizar` variable?

Answer (score 0):

To get column names of data.frame `df`:

```
column_names <- names(df)
```